# Can't import JetBrains Atom OneDark Theme into Android Studio Mac

Tags: android-studio

I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 on a Mac.

JetBrains' [Atom OneDark Theme](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12178-atom-onedark-theme) says it's

```
Compatible with IntelliJ IDEA (Ultimate, Community, Educational), Android Studio and 13 more
```

I downloaded `atom-onedark-theme.jar` to my Downloads folder.

I opened Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > Color Scheme > gear icon > Import Scheme.

The error message is

```
Import failed: /Users/TDK/Downloads/atom-onedark-theme.jar is not a valid scheme. There are no color schemes in the chosen file.
```

Then I tried to import `Material Theme UI` and nothing happens. No error message, no new theme appears in the list.

What did I do wrong?

I imported this `Atom DarkOne` into Visual Studio without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install the themes as plugins before I could select them as themes. Android Studio > Preferences > Plugins > search for the themes you want. Restart the IDE and the you can go to Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > Color Scheme to select a new theme.

`Atom One Dark (Material)` is my favorite.